# How to Change Bootstrap navbar width to Fit inside a Column-md-1

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So i am using bootstrap 3 and I cant seem to get my minimal navigation menu to fit inside a col-md-1 to allow my other colums to line up across the top of the page. It seems to offset it and sends my other columns below it. How Do i Fix this??? Below is the html and a link to a my full coding. https://jsfiddle.net/Digigod/9qncuhog/2/

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">
         <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-left navbar-minimal animate" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-toggler animate">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="navbar-menu animate">
        <li>
            <a class="menu_nav" href="#about-us" class="animate">
                <span class="desc animate"> HOME </span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>

            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="menu_nav" href="#blog" class="animate">
                <span class="desc animate"> Artist </span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="menu_nav" href="#contact-us" class="animate">
                <span class="desc animate"> Music </span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cd"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="menu_nav" href="#contact-us" class="animate">
                <span class="desc animate"> Videos </span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="menu_nav" href="#contact-us" class="animate">
                <span class="desc animate"> Services </span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="menu_nav" href="#contact-us" class="animate">
                <span class="desc animate"> Contact Us </span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7"><b>FOLLOW US:</b>
<i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> 
<i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i> 
<i class="fa fa-google-plus-square"></i></div>

<div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2"></div> 

<div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `.col-xs-7` column must also be inside your `.container` and `.row`.

Comment: I have tried this method its still doesnt work. It unorders my navigational menu